# LINQ query for getting row with max date in grouped table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-dataset

I have following datatable structure

```
ID    Date            Vendor  Grade
 1    20-nov-2013     xyz      A
 2    26-Apr-2013     abc      B
 1    21-nov-2013     pqr      D
 1    10-nov-2013     abc      C
 2    15-dec-2013     pqr      A
 2    20-May-2013     abc      B
```

What i want group this table on column `ID` and then select the row that has maximum dateTime value

Sample Answer would be for this table is

```
ID    Date            Vendor  Grade
 1    21-nov-2013     pqr      D
 2    15-dec-2013     pqr      A
```

I have tried following so far but struck with no clue what to do next

```
var chk = (from s in dt.AsEnumerable()
          where s.Field<int>("ID") == 1 || s.Field<int>("ID") == 2            
          select s).GroupBy(k => k.Field<int>("ID")});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group your rows by `ID`, then sort each group of rows by `Date` and select first one row:

```
var chk = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
          let id = r.Field<int>("ID")
          where id == 1 || id == 2
          group r by id into g
          select g.OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<DateTime>("Date")).First();
```

Produces

```
ID    Date            Vendor  Grade
 1    21-nov-2013     pqr      D
 2    15-dec-2013     pqr      A
```

Comment: @this will give just one data he needs all

Comment: I have used where condition to filter the data in datatable

Comment: @RajeevKumar you can put where condition here, if you need

Comment: @techloverr what do you mean by `he needs all`? I can see single row selected for each id

Comment: can i make it work by putting where condition first in datatable and then grouped it by any means

Answer (score 0):

**Query** syntax:

```
  var chk = from r in dt.AsEnumerable() /*where 1=1 */
                  group r by r.Field<int>("ID") into g
                  select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Field<int>("ID")).First();
```

**Fluent** syntax :

```
 dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID")).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Field<int>("ID")).First());
```

Comment: How does this answer related to question? OP has different fields and he wants select rows with max date, not simply max date value

Comment: @lazyberezovsky grouping a rows by key and select the max value for that key.....isn't it ?